# Android circle reveal animation not smooth

Tags: android, animation, view, android-animation, linear-interpolation

am creating login and signup in same page with circle reveal animation ,switch the view using a floating action button, it very lag when switching one view to another view,

Login page Contain two relative layout and a floating action button
one view for login and other for signup
when floating action button click view will switch to another ie login to signup and vise versa.. i achieved but it is too lag how can i make it smooth

in tab(big screen) it works very smoothly(am creating two layout one for mobile and other for tab)
can anyone help me.. this is my code..

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void viewMenu() {

        if (!isOpen) {

//            int x = layoutContent.getRight();
//            int y = layoutContent.getBottom();
            int x = Math.round(fab.getX() + fab.getWidth() / 2);
            int y = Math.round(fab.getY() - fab.getHeight());
            int startRadius = 0;
            int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(layoutMain.getWidth(), layoutMain.getHeight());

            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),android.R.color.white,null)));
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cross);

            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(layoutButtons, x, y, startRadius, endRadius);


            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            layoutButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
//                    fst_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            anim.start();

            isOpen = true;

        } else {

//            int x = layoutButtons.getRight();
//            int y = layoutButtons.getBottom();
            int x = Math.round(fab.getX() + fab.getWidth() / 2);
            int y = Math.round(fab.getY() + fab.getHeight()/2) - toolbar.getHeight();
            int startRadius = Math.max(layoutContent.getWidth(), layoutContent.getHeight());
            int endRadius = 0;

            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.colorAccent,null)));
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
//            fst_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(layoutButtons, x, y, startRadius, endRadius);


            anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    layoutButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            anim.start();

            isOpen = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you rephrase ypur question, so it would be more visible, what you want to achieve. Also please try to enchance question quality so it would be understandable for other users.

Comment: In most cases there is too much work performing on main thread.

Comment: i tried is it ok ?. am new here..

Comment: can you help me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you could use `FastOutLinearInInterpolator()` instead of `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()`, and add `anim.setDuration()` with animation duration you want.
And set `layoutButtons.setVisibility()` to `View.INVISIBLE` like described here in the bottom of the [article](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view#Reveal).

Furthermore, you can rid of from `Math.round()` when you calculate view *x, y* coordinates.

It worked great for my case.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/EgorSalenko/230b39d2c840ac0f3010aa599ec98ad7) is my example code